# Docker context in Container Builder. The Dockerfile must be within the build context

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry, google-cloud-platform

I'm not understanding the Docker context in Container Builder. I have a Dockerfile under services/device-registry/base/build/docker/php/Dockerfile but I want my build context to be services/device-registry My Container Builder step looks like this:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-f', './base/build/docker/php/Dockerfile', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/device-registry-php', '.' ]
  dir: 'services/device-registry'
  id: 'device-registry-php'
```

And I get the error ***unable to prepare context: The Dockerfile (/workspace/services/device-registry/base/build/docker/php/D‌​ockerfile) must be within the build context (.)***

Comment: In the end this worked for me: https://gist.github.com/Simon-Ince/e01835e920285dc45049d8a1e9573876 But I'm still not sure why the first one wasnt working.

Answer (score 4):

You this is a `docker build` limitation/by-design. This is not related to Google Container Builder.

Files you're sending into to a `docker build` command has to be at the SAME or NESTED folders as the `Dockerfile`.  In your command above, it violates this.